# Chrome: How can I open a tab that includes only certain extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

When I do web development on win10, I use Chrome to preview my work. However, some of my regular extensions can occasionally interfere with my app rendering correctly.

I'd like to be able to open a tab that has *only certain extensions*: specifically, the few I use for web development.

I know I can open an incognito tab & tell Chrome to permit my developer extensions, but then I have to keep my developer extensions running in regular Chrome, which isn't optimal.

I've taken to using Chrome Canary for development, but I'm not sure when/how its bleeding edge features will affect my app's rendering.

Is there a way to open this sort of tab in vanilla Chrome?

Comment: Use a separate [portable version of chrome](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable) with the extensions you need ...

Comment: Maybe you could modify your extensions to stop working if you are on a certain website? But I think running a separate chrome instance is easier.

Comment: thanks all. the portable version seems like the lowest-friction solution; very clever. if you want to make it a formal answer I'll accept it, David

Comment: Maybe not an only tab but the ability to quickly change "context" and enable/ disable several extensions fast - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/context/aalnjolghjkkogicompabhhbbkljnlka?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog If this works I can post as an answer

Comment: @Brandon - Let me know if this helps